# How to read XML column in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have never used XML in SQL Server 2008, I need to extract a list of fields into a variable table how do you do it?

Given that I have a column called xmldata in a XMLMain table that looks like something like below how do I extract the list of fields in sql?

![enter image description here][1]

```
<?mso-infoPathSolution name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:SampleForm:-myXSD-2014-03-29T09-41-23" solutionVersion="1.0.0.18" productVersion="15.0.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="http://bipc20/sites/team-1303/FormServerTemplates/SampleForm.xsn"?>
<?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document" versionProgid="InfoPath.Document.4"?>
<my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2014-03-29T09:41:23" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-US">
<my:field1>1</my:field1>
<my:field2>2</my:field2>
<my:field3>true</my:field3>
<my:field4 xsi:nil="true" />
<my:field5 xsi:nil="true" />
<my:field6>4</my:field6>
<my:FormName>2014-04-01T15:11:47</my:FormName>
<my:Repeating>hi</my:Repeating>
<my:Repeating xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2014-03-29T09:41:23">hello</my:Repeating>
<my:Repeating xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2014-03-29T09:41:23">how are  you?</my:Repeating>
</my:myFields>
```

I want to extract value of Repeating field as comma separated like for ex. in Repeating we have three values (hi,hello,how are you?)

can anyone please help me.?

Comment: It would be easier to help you with a query if you could post the actual XML instead of a picture of the XML.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson i have edited my question, so that my xml is visible to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
with xmlnamespaces('http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2014-03-29T09:41:23' as my)
select M.XMLData.value('(/my:myFields/my:field1/text())[1]', 'int') as field1,
       M.XMLData.value('(/my:myFields/my:field2/text())[1]', 'int') as field2,
       M.XMLData.value('(/my:myFields/my:field3/text())[1]', 'bit') as field3,
       M.XMLData.value('(/my:myFields/my:FormName/text())[1]', 'datetime') as FormName,
       (
         select ','+R.X.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
         from M.XMLData.nodes('/my:myFields/my:Repeating') as R(X)
         for xml path(''), type
       ).value('substring(text()[1], 2)', 'nvarchar(max)') as Repeating
from XMLMain as M
```

Result:

```
field1      field2      field3 FormName                Repeating
----------- ----------- ------ ----------------------- -----------------------
1           2           1      2014-04-01 15:11:47.000 hi,hello,how are  you?
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael, This is what i was looking for. Thank you once again.